# Create SNS notifications for any new bucket created across AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

Is it possible to create SNS topic configuration for any new bucket that is created in S3 account ?

I am trying to do this in cloudformation but this works only for one bucket

```
"NotificationConfiguration": {
      "TopicConfigurations": [
          {
              "Event": {
                   "Ref": "**"
              },
              "Topic": {
                    "Ref": "S3SNSTopic"
              }
          }
       ]
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about dynamically creating a topic every time a new bucket is created or creating different topic for a known list of buckets?

Comment: I am trying to sending an event to an exiting unique topic when new (dynamic) bucket is created

Comment: What comes to my mind is to use CloudTrail -> CloudWatch -> metric filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a CloudWatch Event for the appropriate API action (assuming you have CloudTrail turned on) and the event interacts with an SNS topic.